# Modify objects while iterating 2 Lists using java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

```java
List<Account> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Order> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

list1.stream().forEach(l1 -> list2.stream()
        .forEach(l2 -> {
            if (l1.getOrderId() == l2.getOrderId())
                l1.setStatus(l2.getStatus());
        }));
```

I was doing like this. It worked fine but now I have another situation where if orderId is not present in list2 set the status as "invalid" for that particular l1.
OrderId is unique in both the tables.
Hope this gives better understanding.

Comment: modifying objects while using Streams, in general, is not a good idea.

Comment: "I want to code this using Streams" why?

Comment: @Andy I want Functional programming.

Comment: Cool buddy. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** Thanks for the edit of your question, it makes a lot more sense now. I think that this should do what you’re after:

```
    list1.forEach(acc -> acc.setStatus(list2.stream()
            .filter(o -> o.getOrderId() == acc.getOrderId())
            .findAny()
            .map(Order::getStatus)
            .orElse("invalid")));
```

I am using `Iterable.forEach()` and then `Collection.stream()` and `Optional.map()` for a functional way of calculating the status to be set.